# Consolidated list of free features

Tags: product

I am new to Magento and we are planning to use it for our new store.
We are in the process of finalizing the budget for first release where we need minimal set of features ( for sure there should not be any compromise to the  features which must be present for a good store example is one page checkout, Guest checkout).

For this we need what all the features are freely available in the CE and what all are paid.

is there any where I can see what all the features are free?

Answer (score 3):

For Magento Enterprise there is a [very nice PDF](https://info.magento.com/rs/magentocommerce/images/Magento%20Full%20Features%20List%20052714.pdf) outlining all of the features.
You could use it as a starting point. Next to that the [CE resources page](http://magento.com/resources/technical) might give you some info.

On the paid features, Do you mean paid 3th party modules? There are a lot of those and it's impossible to have a list of all of their features.

Checkout some of the larger vendors like Aheadworks and Amasty and of course you can find most modules on [Magento Connect](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/)